# Is a good practice to used shifted unsigned numbers as an index number of array

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

Defining the enum as flags in the following way

```
    typedef enum
    {
        NOT_PID = 0,
        PID1 = (1U << 0),
        PID2 = (1U << 1),
        NUM_PID = 3

    } pid_t;

    float m_derivative[pid_t::NUM_PID];
```

and using it as follows:

```
    m_derivative[pid_t::PID1] = 4.0
    m_derivative[pid_t::PID2] = 3.0
```

Is good practice to used shifted unsigned numbers as a index number of array in this way?

Comment: In the particular code you've shown, there's no real problem. However, if you tried to add more `PIDn` values, so that (say), you had `PID8 = (1U << 8)` then you would need the array to be *at least* 257 elements in size.

Comment: You really only need the shifts if youre trying to make a bitfeid.  If you just want array indicies [0, 1, 2, 3, ..] then just use the default values like `enum pid_t
    {
        NOT_PID,
        PID1,
        PID2,
        NUM_PID = 3

    }`

Comment: @NathanOliver: Would you even want to assign `NUM_PID`? I'd usually let it be the next value, with a big comment similar to, `// Add new values before this`.

Comment: @FredLarson Actually I would do what you do.  I just didn't as I didn't have room in the comments

Comment: Instead of `typedef enum {...} pid_t;`, in C++ use `enum pid_t {...};`

Comment: Are you ever going to access `m_derivative[pid_t::PID1 | pid_t::PID2]` ? In that case you'd need `NUM_PID = 4` in your example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens if you go one further?

```
typedef enum
{
    NOT_PID = 0,
    PID1 = (1U << 0),
    PID2 = (1U << 1),
    PID3 = (1U << 2),
    NUM_PID = 4
} pid_t;

float m_derivative[pid_t::NUM_PID];
m_derivative[pid_t::PID3] = 4.0; // out of bounds
```

Here, `PID3 = 4` which is not less than `NUM_PID`. This causes an out of bounds access.

If you define `NUM_PID` to be large enough, then it's no longer the number of PIDs as the name implies. Moreover, if you have a relatively large number of PIDs, then you are going to waste a lot of memory. For example, with 20 PIDs, you need an array of 2^20 = 1048576 elements, which is 4MB assuming 32-bit enumerators.

If you actually need the powers of two somewhere, produce them whenever you need them:

```
enum pid_t { NOT_PID, PID1, PID2, PID3, NUM_PID };
auto pid_bit(pid_t pid) -> unsigned int {
    if (pid == NOT_PID) {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1u << (pid-1);
}
```

Also note that, in C++, you don't need to typedef your enum.

Answer (score 1):

Using enum values as array indices is good practice. In fact, Scott Meyers suggests this in item 10 of "Effective Modern C++".

However, defining the enum values with bit shifting looks shifty.
You won't get a contiguous array. it this is important to you - avoid this.